# Understanding Memory Usage in Python in class vs variable

Tags: python-3.x, memory

Basic python question: My program needs to loop more than a million time.

And I found out that the `Memory` usage is huge at the end.

So, I decided to do some experiment.

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sample = 0

    def increase(self, amt):
        self.sample += amt

    def replace(self, amt):
        self.sample = amt


def int_test():
    sample = Sample()
    print('memory usage: {}'.format(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss))
    for i in range(10**6):
        sample.increase(i)
    print(sample.sample)
    print('memory usage: {}'.format(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss))


def int_replace_test():
    sample = Sample()
    print('memory usage: {}'.format(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss))
    for i in range(10**6):
        sample.replace(i)
    print(sample.sample)
    print('memory usage: {}'.format(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss))


def int_simple_test():
    sample = 1
    print('memory usage: {}'.format(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss))
    for i in range(10 ** 6):
        sample += i
    print(sample)
    print('memory usage: {}'.format(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss))


def int_simple_replace_test():
    sample = 1
    print('memory usage: {}'.format(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss))
    for i in range(10 ** 6):
        sample = i
    print(sample)
    print('memory usage: {}'.format(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    int_test()
    print('--')
    int_replace_test()
    print('--')
    int_simple_test()
    print('--')
    int_simple_replace_test()
    print('--')
```

And this is the result.

```
memory usage: 64917504
499999500000
memory usage: 72101888
--
memory usage: 72101888
999999
memory usage: 80195584
--
memory usage: 80195584
499999500001
memory usage: 80195584
--
memory usage: 80195584
499999500001
memory usage: 80195584
--
```

So, when I m simply declaring a variable, and updating it or assigning it to a new value, the memory usage is not changed.

But if I put that variable into a class, and control it with functions, it is eating up memory. My guess is the old memory is not being released when it is updated.

I tested both updating and replacing it since I initially doubted whether it has some effect.

If it's just one variable, I would just use the variable approach. But in actual code, I need to put them in a class since there are multiple variables that needs manipulating in each loop.

I come from `Java` world, and just started using `python`. So, I m not really familiar with the best practices.

Does my logic with `class` need to be updated to avoid the memory consumption?

Comment: Try your test again, calling the simple variable tests *before* the class-based tests this time.  I suspect that a lot of your early memory growth is actually one-time allocations of pools of `int` values (since you're going through a huge number of distinct values), rather than any systematic difference between the two approaches.

Comment: @jasonharper I just did. same results. `variable` tests have the same memory while `class` tests have some increase.

Comment: Curious.... to determine if it is the method call, or the class variable behind this- how about a test where you increase sample.sample+=i inside the test loop?

Comment: @visibleman just tested that. Memory won't increase. So, it's the method call.

Comment: I ran your code and memory usage stayed at 9484 (its kilobytes on my machine) for all cases. linux, python 3.5, from the command line. Python 3.6 was slightly smaller at 9324 for all cases.

Comment: Could it be just a Garbage Collection timing issue? (i.e, if the GC have time to run before the last print call or not)

Comment: @visibleman - GC only runs when normal ref counting doesn't clean out circular references. I don't think GC even touched the memory here.

Comment: @tdelaney I was running it via `debug` mode of `pycharm`. When I run it directly, there is no issue. I guess the problem is the `pycharm debugger`

Comment: @william - makes sense!

Comment: This was a useful question for highlighting how execution environment can affect profiling. I don't know whether we should close or answer this one!